# How to pick up selective fields from a command output in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am learning powershell as part of windows administration and I have a bit of a problem. I need to run sysinfo command for various systems and pick up the `OS Name`, `OS Version` , `Total Physical Memory` and other fields from the output. My problem is the output is not a powershell object, so I can't use property based processing. What can I do to pick up only these fields ? I tried using findstr, but for fields like Hotfix, which have multiple values, it only picks up the first line.

Command

```
systeminfo /S <IP Address> /U Administrator /P <Password>
```

Output:

```
    Host Name:                 TEST
    OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard
    OS Version:                6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
    OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
    OS Configuration:          Standalone Server
    OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
```

Answer (score 1):

Running `systeminfo -?` indicates the command supports a format option. Using the CSV format, you can let PowerShell import the output directly:

```
systeminfo -fo CSV | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

This will return a custom PSObject containing properties like `OS Name`, `Host Name`, etc, which you can access with quotes (as [Matt mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25326379/2495)): `$csv.'OS Name'`

---

For reference, here is what `systeminfo -?` shows on my machine:

```
SYSTEMINFO [/S system [/U username [/P [password]]]] [/FO format] [/NH]

Description:
    This tool displays operating system configuration information for
    a local or remote machine, including service pack levels.

Parameter List:
    /S      system           Specifies the remote system to connect to.

    /U      [domain\]user    Specifies the user context under which
                             the command should execute.

    /P      [password]       Specifies the password for the given
                             user context. Prompts for input if omitted.

    /FO     format           Specifies the format in which the output
                             is to be displayed.
                             Valid values: "TABLE", "LIST", "CSV".

    /NH                      Specifies that the "Column Header" should
                             not be displayed in the output.
                             Valid only for "TABLE" and "CSV" formats.

    /?                       Displays this help message.

Examples:
    SYSTEMINFO
    SYSTEMINFO /?
    SYSTEMINFO /S system
    SYSTEMINFO /S system /U user
    SYSTEMINFO /S system /U domain\user /P password /FO TABLE
    SYSTEMINFO /S system /FO LIST
    SYSTEMINFO /S system /FO CSV /NH
```

Answer (score 0):

I know i can make the answer better but at least a start would be this:

```
$file = systeminfo
$file | Where-Object{($_ -like "OS*") -or ($_ -like "Host Name:*")}
```

Capture the systeminfo into a variable (array) that can be piped into Where-Object to parse out the data you are looking for

output:

```
Host Name:                 TE_ST
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise 
OS Version:                6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
```

I am trying to turn it into a proper object to improve my answer

Answer (score 0):

I am making another answer in a attempt to not loose the simplicity of my first answer. To continue:

```
$sysInfo= systeminfo
$output = $sysInfo | 
        Where-Object{($_ -like "OS*") -or ($_ -like "Host Name:*")} | 
        ForEach-Object{ $_ -replace ":\s+"," = "}
ConvertFrom-StringData($output | Out-String)
```

Again, the `systeminfo` is captured into a variable `$sysInfo`. Capture the desired output in `$output`.

This time I run each line with a replace using the ForEach-Object `-replace ":\s+"," = "`. The reason is I am going to turn the text into a hash table which is a series of `name = value`. The regex replace changes the colon and any following white space into `=`.

The $output is of type `System.Object[]`. However we need it to be a string in my example to it can be put into [ConvertFrom-StringData](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849900.aspx) which is why we pipe $output into Out-String.

That being said you get the following:

```
Name                           Value                                                                  
----                           -----                                                                  
OS Manufacturer                Microsoft Corporation                                                  
OS Version                     6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601                                     
OS Configuration               Member Workstation                                                     
OS Name                        Microsoft Windows 7 Professional                                       
Host Name                      C4093                                                                  
OS Build Type                  Multiprocessor Free
```

Which you can now use powershell cmd-lets against

```
$osInfo = ConvertFrom-StringData($output | Out-String)
$osInfo."Os Name"
```

`"Os Name"` needs to be in quotes as it contains a space.